# x equals puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I'm looking for a 2-word phrase, (6) (5). Try to figure out which phrase it is given the image below.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer here is:

> **TENNIS COURT**

The first thing to notice is that...

> ...the letters and shapes can be overlaid, equating each point to a letter:
>
>  [image: Overlaid image]

Now, if we try to...

> ...position each of the small shapes so that these points line up (i.e. so that all points labelled 'A' overlay each other, then all the points labelled 'B', etc.), we form an image that looks something like this (approximated in MS Excel):
>
>  [image: Image formed by overlaying points labelled with the same letter]

What is this? Well...

> Let's shade everything green and make the lines white. This is now recognisably the markings of a **TENNIS COURT**. In fact, let's make the centre line grey, since it, in fact, represents the net (hence why I suspect the vertical line at the top of the original image was included as a 'piece' in its own right):
>
>  [image: Tennis court]

As for the title...

> In Roman numerals, 'x equals' can be read as 'ten is', i.e. **Tennis**!

Comment: You got the correct image! But what would happen if you painted each rectangle green (which I initially wanted to do, but changed my mind), will the title make sense then?

Comment: @Prim3numbah Argh! Yes it makes sense!

Comment: That's it! Well done :)